# How can I take screenshots with a delay?

Tags: screenshot

Sometimes I have to take multiple screenshots because when you trace the area, it highlights the area with a light-blue tint, and the screenshot is too fast and it catches that blue tint. Eventually it turns out right, but it's more and more often now that I have to take multiple screenshots before it finally takes one that isn't tinted blue from the selection screen.

Is there a way to delay the shutter by a millisecond?

Comment: Have you considered recording the screen? It seems like the simples solution to me. You record it, and then pick out the frame that you want...

Comment: I could take a picture of the entire desktop and then cut out the part that I want, sure.   But that's extra steps I'm hoping to avoid.  I don't want the entire desktop, I want a small piece of it (A window or a dialogue box for example) to insert into presentations and pdfs.  having to crop a full screenshot down to the piece that I want is far less convenient than just dragging a selection box around that part in the first place.  Like I said, low priority, not really a big deal.

Comment: You could always modify the code to add a delay. I might be able to do that for you and make you a PPA to add

Comment: Thanks for the offer.  But it's not that much of a priority that I need to replace the program entirely and make people do extra work.  Was asking on the off chance that there might be the equivalent of a configuration file hiding somewhere that I can alter.  But if it requires recoding and rebuilding, it's easier to just take an extra couple of whacks at it when that happens.  Eventually it gets the timing right.  Thanks for the offer though.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug than a question, the screenshot app should not capture the blue tint.

Comment: Posted a bug to launchpad, please confirm the bug to get this seen to :)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1586533

Answer (score 0):

Yup, there is. Simply open the Screenshot program and change "Grab after a delay of X seconds".

Comment: Unfortunately that is only an option with taking a screenshot of the entire screen or of a particular window.  When choosing to take a screenshot of a box selection, that option grays out.  I did search around hoping that maybe there was a flag I could toggle to initiate that option in the box-selection screenshot, but no luck. Thank you though.  I appreciate the response.